# Threaded program crash on Wine (Windows native OK)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, wine

I wanted to run a C++ program that I developed on Windows 7 and compiled with Visual Studio 2013, on Ubuntu 14.04, using Wine 1.6.

As expected, I was getting a lot of errors, so I tried something simple instead:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello main\n";
}
```

I linked to the static version of the C++ runtime library (`Runtime Library` to set to `/MT`) so I wouldn't need any .dll's. And this worked just fine.

[image]

But then I added some very simple threading:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void call_from_thread() {
    std::cout << "Hi from thread\n";
}

int main() {
    std::thread t(call_from_thread);
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

This compiled and ran fine on my Windows machine (of course), but running it on Ubuntu through Wine gave me some ugly errors:
[image]

Clicking "Show Details" shows nothing and exits Wine, but clicking "Close" spits out more output:
[image]

I tried again, this time changing linking to the shared version of the C++ Runtime Library (`Runtime Library` to set to `/MD`), then grabbed `msvcr120.dll` and `msvcp120.dll` from my `C:/Windows/SysWOW64` directory on Windows machine for Wine to use. But I got pretty much the same error messages.

Searching through Google [suggests](https://www.winehq.org/docs/winedev-guide/threading) that threading is supported by Wine, so I have no idea why my program fails.

Comment: What are the errors? Tired eyes cannot see the text. And the site and search engines cannot index the text. The text needs to be added to the question (its OK to keep the images, but we need the text).

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest version of Wine (1.7.33 at the moment) and using a clean wineprefix made the threading example just work fine. I should have expected this since Wine 1.6 was released in July 2013.